# r.composite gives blank image output in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis

While running r.composite in GRASSGIS GUI command the image formed looks absolutely blank. The data I used is listed here below.

IRS-LISS III Multispectral coverages. (i.e. band 2, 3 and 4 for Blue, Green and red respectively)

Comment: have you fixed the region before ?

Comment: Of course, I fixed my region from 16-24N and 84-90E. In fact d.rgb command is working fine. I can see my desired FCC image and NCC image as I need. But while running r.composite command, the out put image looks blank. Even after selecting the layer and zooming the layer to the display extent, it doesn't appear. I'm running it on 32bit Windows 7 SP1. Thanks for the response Mr. Gene.

Comment: You need to fix the region on one of the RGB files, before applying `r.composite`. If not -> blank file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I set the region again after importing the individual bands to the defined bounds for all coverage. And now I succeeded in running r.composite and exporting the MSI to TIFF format also. Again Thanks a lot Mr. Gene.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @gene:

> You need to fix the region on one of the RGB files, before applying
>   r.composite. If not -> blank file.

It looks like this worked for you because you commented:

> I set the region again after importing the individual bands to the
>   defined bounds for all coverage. And now I succeeded in running
>   r.composite and exporting the MSI to TIFF format also.